# xs3p: handling include-tags

Tags: xslt, xsd, include, documentation

I just wanted to generate a documentation of a schema with xs3p.

The problem is, as far as I understand it, that the schema is split into several files and that xs3p did not process the include-tags of the master file: The result is a documentation containing only the root element.

What did I do exactly?

1. I unzipped the xs3p-download into a certain directory
2. I copied all schema files into the directory
3. I called *saxonb-xslt master.xsd xs3p.xsl >doku.html* (under Ubuntu Trusty, if that matters)

Can you give me any help? I assume, there are two lines to solve the problem:

1. Making xs3p process the include-tags
2. Integrating all xsd-files into a single one — how would this work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the following xsl:param in xs3p.xsl :

```
   <!-- If 'true', searches 'included' schemas for schema components
        when generating links and XML Instance Representation tables. -->
   <xsl:param name="searchIncludedSchemas">true</xsl:param>

   <!-- If 'true', searches 'imported' schemas for schema components
        when generating links and XML Instance Representation tables. -->
   <xsl:param name="searchImportedSchemas">true</xsl:param>

   <!-- File containing the mapping from file locations of external
        (e.g. included, imported, refined) schemas to file locations
        of their XHTML documentation. -->
   <xsl:param name="linksFile">xs3p_links.xml</xsl:param>
```

Your included/imported schemas must have been previously transformed into a my_transformed_included_schema.html file, and you need to define a xs3p_links.xml file in order to assign some imported/included schema to theirs location such as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<links xmlns="http://titanium.dstc.edu.au/xml/xs3p">
       <schema file-location="my-included-schema.xsd" docfile-location="./my_transformed_included_schema.html"/>
</links>
```

Hope that'll help !

Comment: Thank you for your help!